# Transpose of a vector using numpy

Tags: numpy, ipython, transpose

I am having an issue with Ipython - Numpy. I want to do the following operation:

```
x^T.x
```

with [image: formula] and x^T the transpose operation on vector x. x is extracted from a txt file with the instruction:

```
x = np.loadtxt('myfile.txt')
```

The problem is that if i use the transpose function

```
np.transpose(x)
```

and uses the shape function to know the size of x, I get the same dimensions for x and x^T. Numpy gives the size with a L uppercase indice after each dimensions. e.g.

```
print x.shape
print np.transpose(x).shape

(3L, 5L)
(3L, 5L)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this, and compute x^T.x as a matrix product?

Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know why does this work:

`x[:,None]`

Comment: The actual code used by the OP is given in the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19238811/1647894).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained by others, transposition won't "work" like you want it to for 1D arrays.
You might want to use `np.atleast_2d` to have a consistent scalar product definition:

```
def vprod(x):
    y = np.atleast_2d(x)
    return np.dot(y.T, y)
```

Answer (score 32):

What `np.transpose` does is reverse the shape tuple, i.e. you feed it an array of shape `(m, n)`, it returns an array of shape `(n, m)`, you feed it an array of shape `(n,)`... and it returns you the same array with shape`(n,)`.

What you are implicitly expecting is for numpy to take your 1D vector as a 2D array of shape `(1, n)`, that will get transposed into a `(n, 1)` vector. Numpy will not do that on its own, but you can tell it that's what you want, e.g.:

```
>>> a = np.arange(4)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a.T
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a[np.newaxis, :].T
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I used numpy matrix to solve it:

```
# assuming x is a list or a numpy 1d-array 
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]

# convert it to a numpy matrix
>>> x = np.matrix(x)
>>> x
matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

# take the transpose of x
>>> x.T
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]])

# use * for the matrix product
>>> x*x.T
matrix([[55]])
>>> (x*x.T)[0,0]
55

>>> x.T*x
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10],
        [ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15],
        [ 4,  8, 12, 16, 20],
        [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]])
```

While using numpy matrices may not be the best way to represent your data from a coding perspective, it's pretty good if you are going to do a lot of matrix operations!

Answer (score 1):

For starters `L` just means that the type is a long int. This shouldn't be an issue. You'll have to give additional information about your problem though since I cannot reproduce it with a simple test case:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(12).reshape((4,3))

In [3]: a
Out[3]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

In [4]: a.T #same as np.transpose(a)
Out[4]:
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])

In [5]: a.shape
Out[5]: (4, 3)

In [6]: np.transpose(a).shape
Out[6]: (3, 4)
```

There is likely something subtle going on with your particular case which is causing problems. Can you post the contents of the file that you're reading into `x`?

Answer (score 1):

This is either the inner or outer product of the two vectors, depending on the orientation you assign to them. Here is how to calculate either without changing `x`.

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
inner = x.dot(x)
outer = numpy.outer(x, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file 'myfile.txt' contain lines such as

```
5.100000 3.500000 1.400000 0.200000 1
4.900000 3.000000 1.400000 0.200000 1
```

Here is the code I run:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('iris.txt')
x = data[1,:]

print x.shape
print np.transpose(x).shape
print x*np.transpose(x)
print np.transpose(x)*x
```

And I get as a result

```
(5L,)
(5L,)
[ 24.01   9.     1.96   0.04   1.  ]
[ 24.01   9.     1.96   0.04   1.  ]
```

I would be expecting one of the two last result to be a scalar instead of a vector, because x^T.x (or x.x^T) should give a scalar.

Comment: You can get what you are after as `np.dot(x, x)`. The `*` operator in numpy represents element-wise multiplication, not matrix multiplication.

Comment: This isn't an answer, and should be made as an edit to your question instead.  Two points: (1) Originally you said that `numpy` wasn't changing the shape of a `(3L, 5L)` array, which was very surprising, but isn't not surprising at all that `(5L,)` stays as `(5L,)`; it's a 1-D object, and its transpose is itself.  Was your original report in error?  (2) `x*np.transpose(x)` is an elementwise multiplication of two 1-D arrays, and therefore a 1-D array.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = np.array([1, 2, 2])
print(b)
print(np.transpose([b]))
print("rows, cols: ", b.shape)
print("rows, cols: ", np.transpose([b]).shape)
```

Results in

```
[1 2 2]
[[1]
 [2]
 [2]]
rows, cols:  (3,)
rows, cols:  (3, 1)
```

Here (3,) can be thought as "(3, 0)". 
However if you want the transpose of a matrix A, np.transpose(A) is the solution. Shortly, [] converts a vector to a matrix, a matrix to a higher dimension tensor.